# How to configure Mac OS X term so that git has color?

Tags: macos, git, command-line-interface

I've seen a Mac OS X git demo online in which it's configured to have multiple colors.

For example, his prompt is amber, his `ls` directory is purple and his `git diff` output has ~ 4 colors (pink, light green, red, pale yellow).

Can you tell me how can I configure Mac OS X terminal to achieve that?  It's definitely Mac OS X Terminal.app, not iTerm.

Comment: Except that superuser.com is still in private beta and yinglcs probably doesn't have access.

Comment: Is there some Super User beta sign-up requirement besides what's mentioned on http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/super-user-semi-private-beta-begins/ ?

Comment: Probably not, but how many users knows about that? It is not like there is a link to that post on superuser.com that the user who gets the question migrated will find when he gets there (if it is, I can't find it).

Comment: This gist has a good config for colors in git on osx. : https://gist.github.com/trey/2722934

Comment: Yet another helpful question closed. Thankfully not before some folks could answer.

Comment: It's well-established by now that Git questions are on-topic; @casperOne's closure here is wrong, and I'm voted to reopen.

Comment: I also voted to reopen, but it seems there is now only one vote (mine). :(

Answer (score 398):

[William Purcell's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156069/how-to-configure-term-on-mac-os-x-with-color/1185938#1185938) only enables color for the 'git diff' command.  Do this to enable colors for all git commands:

```
$ git config --global color.ui true
```

Comment: or you can check this alternative richer choice here: https://gist.github.com/trey/2722934

Comment: this does not work

Answer (score 59):

To display color in the output of git diff, you need to configure git.  Try running

```
$ git config --global color.diff true
```

to set your $HOME/.gitconfig appropriately.

Comment: William, Yes! This is what I was missing.

Answer (score 15):

This is what I use in my .profile file. Works like a charm because it allows me to see the current git branch as well as its state through the color. 
If you want to modify it please note that it's important to [escape color codes](https://serverfault.com/questions/93878/bash-custom-prompt-breaking-wrapping-of-long-command-lines) in order to avoid line feed problems in long lines.

```
# Setting GIT prompt
c_cyan=`tput setaf 6`
c_red=`tput setaf 1`
c_green=`tput setaf 2`
c_sgr0=`tput sgr0`

branch_color ()
{
    if git rev-parse --git-dir >/dev/null 2>&1
    then
        color=""
        if git diff --quiet 2>/dev/null >&2 
        then
            color=${c_green}
        else
            color=${c_red}
        fi
    else
        return 0
    fi
    echo -n $color
}

parse_git_branch ()
{
    if git rev-parse --git-dir >/dev/null 2>&1
    then
        gitver="["$(git branch 2>/dev/null| sed -n '/^\*/s/^\* //p')"]"
    else
        return 0
    fi
echo -e $gitver
}

#It's important to escape colors with \[ to indicate the length is 0
PS1='\u@\[${c_red}\]\W\[${c_sgr0}\]\[\[$(branch_color)\]$(parse_git_branch)\[${c_sgr0}\]$ '
```

Comment: Which .profile file you mentioned?

Comment: @DarshanPurani, I meant to say the `.profile` file in my $bash

Answer (score 13):

It is not normally something you configure the terminal to do... The terminal is unaware of what it is showing but try this in your shell (if you're using bash, in some other shells you don't export but call setenv or something else):

```
export CLICOLOR=1
export TERM=xterm-color
```

You can then use [LSCOLORS generator](http://geoff.greer.fm/lscolors/) to setup something that you can export using something like:

```
export LSCOLORS=fxfxcxdxbxegedabagacad
```

(the above should give you purple directories)

When you're done and satisfied with the result, add the three lines to either your /etc/bashrc or the .bashrc file in your user's home directory.

**Edit:** Also, in your terminal, make sure the checkbox "Display ANSI colors" (on the "Text" page) is checked.

Comment: .bashrc works too? On my mac it's .bash_profile, I know it's .bashrc on Linux but I figured it was different on mac with the whole BSD thing (Also LSCOLORS is different on Linux and BSD/Mac, it seems).

Comment: .bashrc works for me... And yes, it is different. gls uses LS_COLORS (which can also be generated using the page linked to)

Comment: Thanks. But how can one configure to colors like 'wheat' ,'purple' in the prompt or ls output?
or 'pink' in the 'git diff' output.

Thank you.

Comment: The possible colors are the one you can find at the site I linked to, it is part of the standard and when they defined it you were happy if you had a terminal capable of showing 16 colors.

Answer (score 2):

Open the terminal app, then open the preferences dialogue either through the menu (Terminal -> Preferences) or by pressing <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>.  Once the preferences dialogue opens, select the terminal style from the pane on the left, select Text from the button bar, than make sure the "Display ANSI colors" check box is checked.

That will enable the colors on the terminal.  To get colors in the output on the terminal, you will need to embed ANSI color commands in the data being sent to the terminal.  How this is done is dependent on the commands.  For example (as was shown above) the `ls` command has a colors option. For the color codes, do a google lookup for "ansi color".

Comment: Note that the question is already closed as off topic. :)

Answer (score 0):

For colored ls output I would recommend installing the gnu coreutils and using that version of ls instead.  For either version of ls you'll need to pass the correct flag to it, which is --color for the gnu version or -G for the standard OS X version.  So you can do something like

```
alias ls='ls --color'
```

in your .bashrc.

To color your prompt you'll need to use the correct colors codes for your terminal, but mine uses

```
PROMPT="$(print '%{\e[0;38m%}%{\e[1;1m%]%}[%m:%c] %n%%%{\e[0m%}') "
```

to produce

```
[hostname:directory] username%
```

in bold white.