# Enabling Git syntax highlighting for Mac's terminal

Tags: git, terminal, syntax-highlighting

I miss the Git syntax highlighting I had on Windows for every "git .*" command like green staged filenames, some bolding, etc.

How do I enable Git syntax highlighting for Mac's terminal?

Comment: Starting git1.8.4, you should see colors by default. See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17276866/6309).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to configure Mac OS X term so that git has color?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156069/how-to-configure-mac-os-x-term-so-that-git-has-color). The question I'm linking to is closed but it covers the same ground and was asked before this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to color the \`git\` console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10998792/how-to-color-the-git-console)

Answer (score 112, accepted):

```
git config --global color.ui auto
```

Answer (score 14):

For seeing different colors for the diff command, use:

```
git config --global color.diff true
```

To globally change colors for most commands, use:

```
git config --global color.ui true
```

Comment: You don't have to restart Terminal.

Comment: yeah Rob, you're right about not having to restart it. I'm just used to doing it after I configure settings in the terminal.

Answer (score 9):

**Colors in Git**

Git can color its output to your terminal, which can help you visually parse the output quickly and easily. A number of options can help you set the coloring to your preference.

**color.ui**

Git automatically colors most of its output if you ask it to. You can get very specific about what you want colored and how; but to turn on all the default terminal coloring, set color.ui to true:

```
$ git config --global color.ui true
```

When that value is set, Git colors its output if the output goes to a terminal. Other possible settings are false, which never colors the output, and always, which sets colors all the time, even if you’re redirecting Git commands to a file or piping them to another command.

You’ll rarely want color.ui = always. In most scenarios, if you want color codes in your redirected output, you can instead pass a --color flag to the Git command to force it to use color codes. The color.ui = true setting is almost always what you’ll want to use.

```
color.*
```

If you want to be more specific about which commands are colored and how, Git provides verb-specific coloring settings. Each of these can be set to true, false, or always:

```
color.branch
color.diff
color.interactive
color.status
```

In addition, each of these has subsettings you can use to set specific colors for parts of the output, if you want to override each color. For example, to set the meta information in your diff output to blue foreground, black background, and bold text, you can run

```
$ git config --global color.diff.meta "blue black bold"
```

You can set the color to any of the following values: normal, black, red, green, yellow, blue, magenta, cyan, or white. If you want an attribute like bold in the previous example, you can choose from bold, dim, ul, blink, and reverse.

See the git config manpage for all the subsettings you can configure, if you want to do that.

Reference : http://git-scm.com/book/ch7-1.html

Comment: Good summary of all possible options. +1

Answer (score 5):

I've used next solution:

```
git config --global color.diff auto
git config --global color.status auto
git config --global color.branch auto
```

[Original article](http://java.kabit.ru/en/post/Enabling_GIT_syntax_highlighting.html)

Comment: the link is dead

Answer (score 3):

```
git config --global color.diff true
git config --global color.status true
git config --global color.branch true
git config --global color.interactive true
```

There are 4 settings types available:

- **false** - disabled
- **true** - enabled, only in command prompt
- **always** - enabled always

Answer (score 3):

I found [this excellent blog post](http://nathanhoad.net/how-to-colours-in-git) that explains how to set up your git colours and what the standard colours are.  In summary, add the following lines to your `~/gitconfig` file: (*Here's mine - pretty eh?*)

```
[color]
  ui = auto
[color "branch"]
  current = auto
  remote = white reverse
[color "diff"]
  meta = yellow bold
  frag = magenta bold
  new = green bold
[color "status"]
  added = yellow bold
  changed = green
  untracked = cyan
```

In modern versions of Git the `colour.ui` setting is now `auto` by default.

You can use the following as colours:

- `normal`,
- `black`,
- `red`,
- `green`,
- `yellow`,
- `blue`,
- `magenta`,
- `cyan`, and
- `white`.

You can also supply the following optional modifiers:

- `bold`,
- `dim`,
- `ul`,
- `blink`, and
- `reverse`.

Answer (score 1):

Note: starting [git1.8.4 (June 2013)](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/1.8.4.txt#L38-L40), **you won't have to do anything**:

> Many tutorials teach users to set "color.ui" to "auto" as the first thing after you set "`user.name/email`" to introduce yourselves to Git.
>   **Now the variable defaults to "`auto`"**.