# git color.ui does not work on Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: git, ubuntu

I have installed git version 2.1.0 on ubuntu 14.10.

I have a created a local git repository and now I would like to have my branches highlighted with colors in the ubuntu default terminal.

I have done :

```
git config --global color.ui true
```

But it has no effect on the terminal (I have tried to restart it).

This is the content of my ~/.gitconfig file:

```
$ cat ~/.gitconfig 
[alias]
    st = status
        co = checkout
[color]
    ui = true
    branch = auto
    diff = auto
    interactive = auto
    status = auto
```

Any ideas why branches are not coloured/highlighted in the ubuntu terminal when I am inside my repository?

I have read this:

[How to color the Git console in Ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10998792/how-to-color-the-git-console-in-ubuntu?noredirect=1#comment33988696_17278947)

But that does provide any help

[image]

I was expecting something like this:
[image]

Comment: That looks colored to me.  What were you expecting?

Answer (score 0):

If you're expecting the branch name to be colored by `git status` it appears you have to turn this explicitly on.  My guess is it's missing a default color for `color.ui = auto` to apply.

```
[color "status"]
    branch = green
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the branch name in prompt, add to `.bashrc`:

```
gitbranch() {
    [ -d .git ] && git name-rev --name-only @ | sed -e "s/\\(.*\\)/[\\1]/"
}

PS1='\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\] \[\033[00;32m\]$(gitbranch)\[\033[00m\] $ '
```

The branch will be colored green due to  `\[\033[00;32m\]$(gitbranch)\[\033[00m\]`.

[image]