# How do I get a terminal to display colors on CentOS 7 when viewing Git changes.? This is not Git Bash this is just a terminal window

Tags: git, centos, git-status, terminal-color

Can someone direct me to how I can get the color coding option in CentOS for Git?

Is there a specific version that is needed to get this color coding highlight when under the terminal (either terminal or the built-in IntelliJ Terminal?

I had it working on RedHat version but I got switched over to a CentOS VM today and I cannot for the life of me find a way to enable the color coding format for Git so when a file is added or modified it shows a different color for 'git status'.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to color the Git console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10998792/how-to-color-the-git-console)

Comment: @phd I thought that as well but I never call the terminal a console. If the other ticket were to be updated to include terminal in the title then that may help others as well. Being that the answer was there was the reason I put the link into this posting rather than just a random new post with the same answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

git config --global color.ui auto

Just found it, of course: [How to color the Git console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10998792/how-to-color-the-git-console)