# Git: what is extra chars at the end of git branch name "?[m"?

Tags: linux, git, git-bash

Not able to delete all local branches.
Some special characters are appended in the end and git throws following error:

```
git branch | grep -v "develop" | xargs git branch -D

error: branch 'anjum_br?[m' not found.
error: branch 'deploy_doc?[m' not found.
error: branch 'deploy_doc_fix?[m' not found.
```

Comment: that looks suspiciously like vt100 escape sequence if the `?` is replaced with ESC key (0x1b)

Comment: check the git colourize setting, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10998792/how-to-color-the-git-console  . In theory "auto" mode should be off when you're piping

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you run `git branch | grep -v "develop" | od -xcb` to get a better representation of what you're seeing. `ESC [ m` (equivalent to `ESC [ 0 m`) is the terminal sequence for resetting graphics rendition (coloring and other attributes).

The thing you will be looking for is hex `1b` or octal `033`.

If that *is* the case, there's a good chance something is intercepting your streams and injecting these escape sequences into them. The most *likely* cause is your `color.ui` being set to `always`, as shown in the dump below when I set that flag:

```
0000340    6d5b    200a    6d20    7361    6574    1b72    6d5b    000a
          [   m  \n           m   a   s   t   e   r 033   [   m  \n
        133 155 012 040 040 155 141 163 164 145 162 033 133 155 012
```

You can see the escape sequence `033 [ m` in the output stream in that case. Setting that flag to `auto` should use color if it detects output being sent to a terminal, no color otherwise:

```
git config --global color.ui auto
```

Comment: Thanks @paxdiablo indeed that is the issue and after setting it to auto the issue got fixed.

Comment: @KarthikV, so presumably that would be a good reason to upvote/accept the answer, yes? :-)

Comment: Aaargh! I forgot to turn of my `always` setting yesterday and, this morning, got `fatal: remote part of refspec is not a valid name in ?[32mpax-adb9999-fix-device-using-stale-data?[m` when pushing with a script of mine. Can confirm my answer fixes this problem as well :-)