# Git syntax highlighting in iTerm 2

Tags: git, syntax, syntax-highlighting, iterm2

I've just tried to highlight syntax in iTerm 2, but getting no result. I tried config git ([Enabling Git syntax highlighting for Mac's terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8131356/1162790)), played with iTerm profiles but can't reach at result.

Actually, I have [Colbat2](https://github.com/mbadolato/iTerm2-Color-Schemes#cobalt2) theme from this set: https://github.com/mbadolato/iTerm2-Color-Schemes and my shell looks like this:

[image]

and I want it to look like this (but with my color profile):

[image]

Can I do this?

---

**UPDATE**

it only works for `git status`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[@irakli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/554022/irakli) helped me to do this with [oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh).

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It's very simple

`git config --global color.ui auto`

for advanced configuration read this: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration#Colors-in-Git

---

**UPDATE**

forget to mention it's not iTerm 2 specific